# How to get source of the image using RegularExpressions in AS3?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I just want to write a proper regex to get the source of the image from given html text.

```
//HTML TEXT: <img src="angry.gif" alt="Angry face" />

var regEx = //regex Here

var source:Object = regEx.exec(htmlText);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var regex:RegEx  = /src="(.*?)"/i;
var source:String = regex.exec(htmlText)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str:String="Content <img src='imagePath01.jpg' width='88' height='88'/> content content content <img src='imagePath01.jpg' width='88' height='88'/>";
        var imgRegExp:RegExp = /<img[^>]+>/g;//Get (add 'g' end regex) all img in content;
        var imgArr:Array = str.match( imgRegExp );
            for(var i:uint=0;i<imgArr.length;i++){
                trace(imgArr[i]);
                //Get src from img;
                var imgXML:XML = XML(imgArr[i]);
                trace("src: "+imgXML.@src);
            }
```

Happy code !